# Really need another pair of eyes to look at some JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I think it is just something simple, but I have done trying for two days.
All I want to do is just to hide one image and turn on the other image. But nothing seem to work. I have tried clearing the browser cache ever time I test the page. Every time I mouse over on the image map to trigger function Change1(), all it does is hiding image "body_interactive_image_default.png". But it does nothing to image "body_interactive_image_love_lit.png"???? Why????

The browsers I am using: 
Windows Chrome 75.0.3770.100
Windows IE 11
Android Chrome 75.0.3770.100

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function change1() {
    document.getElementById('maptreebg').style = "visibility:hidden; z-index: 0";
    document.getElementById('image1ch').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('image1ch').style = "visibility:visible; z-index: 100";
    document.getElementById('image1ch').width = 290;
    document.getElementById('image1ch').style.width = 290;
    return true;
};
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="div4" class="div4">
        <img name="maptreebg" id="maptreebg" class="img4" alt="" src="/handheld/images/mainbody/body_interactive_image_default.png" usemap="#maptree" />
        <map name="maptree" id="maptree" class="maptree">
            <area id="ar1" shape="poly" coords="3,390,13,381,66,371,113,351,172,313,193,290,217,273,242,259,297,238,344,222,394,213,461,206,521,202,588,205,638,208,694,221,751,249,800,289,835,340,852,397,849,435,815,494,781,526,767,543,728,566,670,586,614,593,521,597,467,590,386,585,309,565,276,554,253,542,228,537,174,503,113,464,76,438,36,416,6,398,4,394" alt="Love" onmouseover="change1()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar2" shape="poly" coords="1990,389,1967,376,1929,373,1879,351,1846,334,1814,308,1786,279,1705,243,1636,220,1549,210,1475,203,1399,204,1331,212,1267,232,1213,268,1179,303,1155,336,1138,390,1138,419,1153,462,1191,510,1226,545,1305,581,1368,593,1448,597,1540,587,1610,586,1674,566,1737,545,1775,530,1841,487,1913,440,1949,416,1968,414,1991,392" alt="Family" onmouseover="change2()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar3" shape="poly" coords="0,849,32,835,73,827,123,806,156,779,188,749,227,723,292,699,358,676,426,667,517,662,609,664,654,671,727,692,770,721,807,755,834,796,850,842,852,880,845,906,814,952,776,993,736,1017,689,1038,635,1051,573,1054,494,1053,435,1045,384,1043,328,1030,272,1013,256,1003,218,993,186,968,149,944,118,924,92,906,66,890,47,878,22,867" alt="Friend" onmouseover="change3()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar4" shape="poly" coords="1987,848,1972,837,1919,826,1868,805,1812,760,1773,728,1668,684,1585,669,1492,661,1385,662,1301,675,1225,712,1178,760,1158,794,1137,853,1143,896,1180,959,1224,1000,1294,1039,1365,1050,1470,1055,1552,1045,1615,1040,1677,1023,1757,996,1815,963,1876,925,1924,890,1969,866,1991,848,1985,850" alt="Colleaque" onmouseover="change4()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar5" shape="poly" coords="0,1305,16,1295,55,1290,109,1266,139,1253,172,1226,208,1193,253,1171,315,1145,388,1128,480,1117,582,1119,644,1124,701,1141,758,1168,808,1211,835,1257,853,1310,847,1359,796,1428,750,1468,713,1487,645,1509,556,1509,493,1509,432,1505,368,1497,317,1482,265,1467,231,1453,187,1429,73,1352,43,1335,21,1326,6,1312" alt="Business" onmouseover="change5()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar6" shape="poly" coords="1987,1302,1960,1293,1914,1281,1865,1262,1815,1222,1777,1191,1692,1154,1614,1130,1520,1121,1409,1117,1331,1126,1280,1145,1216,1178,1177,1225,1159,1251,1140,1302,1138,1323,1145,1358,1174,1409,1222,1456,1263,1481,1330,1503,1373,1510,1463,1512,1539,1503,1606,1500,1667,1485,1707,1476,1732,1460,1771,1449,1827,1412,1909,1355,1980,1319" alt="Educator/Learner" onmouseover="change6()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
            <area id="ar7" shape="poly" coords="47,3567,995,3069,1952,3569,1839,3569,1839,3568,1772,3569" alt="Registration" onmouseover="change7()" href="/handheld.aspx" />
        </map>

        <img name="image1ch" id="image1ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_love_lit.png" />
        <img name="image2ch" id="image2ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_family_lit.png" />
        <img name="image3ch" id="image3ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_friend_lit.png" />
        <img name="image4ch" id="image4ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_clq_lit.png" />
        <img name="image5ch" id="image5ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_bus_lit.png" />
        <img name="image6ch" id="image6ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_ed_ln_lit.png" />
        <img name="image7ch" id="image7ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0" width="0" height="0" alt="" src="/handheld/images/map/body_interactive_image_reg.png" />

    </div>
```

Here is the top of my HTML code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="/handheld/default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WeConnec</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/handheld/style/index.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/handheld/handheld.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Probably due to to the error you are receiving in your console. `.width` is not a method of `.getElementById()`.

Comment: I also tried "document.getElementById('image1ch').style.width = 290;". That did not work either!

Comment: I have no error nor warning in my console???

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the map with images, and reduced the function to its essentials. Notice also that I've removed the `height` and `width` attributes from `img#image1ch`:

```js
function change1() {
  
    var el = document.getElementById('image1ch');
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
    el.style.zIndex = "100";
    el.style.width = "290px";
    el.style.height = "auto";
    
    return true;
};
```

```html
<div id="div4" class="div4">
        <img name="maptreebg" id="maptreebg" class="img4" alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/120/120" usemap="#maptree" />
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" onmouseover="change1()" href="/handheld.aspx" />

        <img name="image1ch" id="image1ch" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0;" alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/140/140" width="0" height="0" />
       
    </div>
```

Comment: symlink: Why would  the height and width attributes from img#image1ch create problem?

Comment: @NoName because they're hardcoded attributes, not part of the CSS

Comment: Oh lord, finally it all make sense. If an image is loaded with zero width and zero height then it is the same as loading nothing into the DOM!!!

Comment: @NoName Yes, it is technically still in the DOM (you can see it in the inspector and source code and alter its style properties), but has no dimensions so is invisible!

Comment: what got me into scratching my head for two days was when an image was loaded with zero width and height then it does not matter if it was blow up with width and height later on there is still nothing to be display. because there was no pixel to begin with. that was what got me lost for two days!!

Comment: Thank you!Thank you!Thank you!Thank you!Thank you!

Comment: @NoName I just realized something. You **can** set the width and height attributes to 0. The problem was with the JavaScript. Instead of `el.style.width = 290;`, I should have made it `el.style.width = "290px";`. See my edit!